# What proceedures should i implement to prevent a Cortex-A55 core reset on a remote target when connecting and disconnecting different GDB sessions?

Tags: arm, gdb, embedded, compiler-optimization, cortex-a

What procedures should I implement to prevent a device reset on a remote target when connecting and disconnecting different GDB sessions?
Assume I run program A, exit GDB and then load a program B in a new GDB session. My hardware would reset. Is there any logical procedure to follow with program A prior to termination that could possibly prevent the reset with the knowledge I will connect program 2.

Since Program A is always consistent, and program B is always different, it is hard to just compile them into one file as this process happens many thousands of times in a test-suite and compiling program A is complicated since it is a highly optimized file vs. Program B we disable optimization.

Comment: Is this just a complicated way of asking "_How to attach/detach/load GDB without resetting the target?_".  ?  If program A (say a bootloader) launches Program B and is in ROM, you probably do not need to do anything, simply load B with a breakpoint in main(), the target will reset and run until it hits the breakpoint.